# How to register a clang preprocessor plugin?

Tags: plugins, clang, preprocessor

I am trying to write a clang plugin for the preprocessor using the C++ interface and would appreciate some help. I've read the clang plugin tutorials using ASTFrontendActions, and tried searching for preprocessor plugins online, but I'm only a little further than I was. I only keep finding references to the same tutorial over and over, or guidance using the C interface.

After digging through header files for 3 days, I think I've narrowed my plugin's parent class to [`clang::PreprocessorFrontendAction`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PreprocessorFrontendAction.html), but can't be sure. I only get build errors when I try to register the plugin because it wants something AST related. (I think because the function the tutorial tells me to use goes back to [this header definition](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/FrontendPluginRegistry_8h_source.html), which uses clang::PluginASTAction.)

The function the tutorial tells me to register with is:

`static FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<MyPlugin> X("my-plugin-name", "my plugin description");`

I've never worked with clang before, so I'm definitely diving in head first. After a week, I feel like I'm drowning in header files. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am clearly not creative enough to apply the AST tutorial to my preprocessor problem.

Edit: So, I've gotten past build errors and everything builds fine now. Unfortunately I have no idea whether I've **actually** registered my plugin. In every function I try to print to the screen but see nothing come out when I run it.

Here is what I have so far.

```
//PluginTest.h
template class llvm::Registry<clang::PreprocessorFrontendAction>;

namespace clang {
    typedef llvm::Registry<PreprocessorFrontendAction> PreprocessorFrontendPluginRegistry;
} // namespace clang


//PluginTest.cpp

namespace {

class TestPreprocessorFrontendAction : public PreprocessorFrontendAction{
    public:
        TestPreprocessorFrontendAction(){
            cerr << "We have a constructor.\n";
        }

    protected:
        virtual void ExecuteAction() {}

        bool BeginSourceFileAction(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef Filename){
            setCompilerInstance(&CI);
            cerr << "Inside BeginSourceFileAction. \n";
            return true;
        }

        //This function should not be called by a PreprocessorFrontendAction
        //and should be overloaded to return an abort. Or so say the headers.
        virtual std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef InFile) {
             cerr << "Inside the badness.\n";
             return null ptr;
         }

         void EndSourceFileAction() {
             cerr << "We have ignition?\n";
         }
};

}


static PreprocessorFrontendPluginRegistry::Add<TestPreprocessorFrontendAction> X(
    "test-plugin",
    "Test preprocessor plugin");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to write a clang plugin that hooks on preprocessor callbacks, you must proceed this way:

```cpp
#include <clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>

using namespace clang;

class MyPPCallbacks : public PPCallbacks {
public:
  // Implement callbacks here
};

class MyASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
public:
  MyASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI) {
    CI.getPreprocessor().addPPCallbacks(std::make_unique<MyPPCallbacks>());
  }
};

class MyPluginASTAction : public PluginASTAction {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef InFile) {
    return std::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>(CI);
  }
  virtual bool ParseArgs(const CompilerIntance &CI, const std::vector<std::string> &args) {
    return true;
  } 
};

static FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<MyPluginAction> X("my-plugin","My Plugin");
```

And implement any callback of `clang::PPCallbacks` in `MyPPCallbacks`.

Follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/banach-space/clang-tutor) to understand how to compile and use a clang plugin.